# JMeter: Add/remove body HEADERS for parameters in multipart/form-data

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm having hard time  to change the header parameters(Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII to Content-Type: application/json ) for POST call in JMeter - sending JSON Text as mutlipart/form-data parameter with content application/json.

Tried this code snippet - sampler.getHeaderManager().remove(1)- its not helping to remove body headers.

```
--v_23LkJlLQpYLpcElRptQYb74v7-UeP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="symbol"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{"name":"man_234","Id":"7d12d44c2"}
--v_23LkJlLQpYLpcElRptQYb74v7-UeP--
```

Can you Please leave me suggestions to get through

Comment: better see the jmeter documentation . https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to amend `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII` bit in the **request body** you need to do it in a different way, to wit: in [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) use the following code:

```
def oldBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
def newBody = oldBody.replaceAll('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII','Content-Type: application/json')
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',newBody,'')
```

However your approach might not be the best one as in case of [multipart request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) each [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) entry can have its own [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) so instead of amending request you need to build it in a different way. See [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article for example of building a multipart request manually.